# passing variable to custom templates - rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my controller, I store in a variable `@template` some view, set a test variable and expects some js response

```
@template = ActionView::Base.new('app/views/devise/sessions', {}, ActionController::Base.new).render(file: 'new').to_s
@test="test"
respond_to do |format|
    format.js {render 'layouts/some_file.js.erb'}
end
```

Then I pass this variable to `some_file.js.erb` and call :

```
$("body").append('<%= escape_javascript(@template) %>');
```

Suppose that in `@tempate` I put <%= @test %>, then `@test` is null. Why is it so ?

Comment: Because your context does not provide access to the @test variable

Comment: Ah ok I understand better, is there a way to do that ?

Comment: Read the doc: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Base/new/class second argument is assign, it should sounds like a hint

Comment: thank you so much , it worked ! Could you post it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Following the documentation (http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Base/new/class), the second argument of `ActionView::Base.new` is `assigns`, which looks like the locals option.

```
@template = ActionView::Base.new('app/views/devise/sessions', { local_var: 21 }, ActionController::Base.new).render(file: 'new').to_s
```

And the variable `local_var` should be available in the corresponding partial.